# Tkinter, Ключевое слово не может быть выражением

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Читаю книгу Майкла Доусона - Программируем на Python (2014). Вот, тема о Tkinter'e. Делаю всё, как на книге.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *

# Создание базового окна.
root = Tk()
root.title('Это я, метка')
root.geometry('200x50')

# Внутри окна создается рамка для размещения других элементов.
app.Frame(root)
app.grid()

# Создание метки внутри рамки.
lbl = Label(app.text = 'Вот она я!')
lbl.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

```
File "D:\Python\labeler.py", line 13
    lbl = Label(app.text = 'Вот она я!')
           ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Если убрать `app` в 13 строке, тогда ошибка исчезнет. Но ведь должно же работать с ним.

Пример из книги:

[image: Пример из книги Майкла Доусона - Программируем на Python(2014)]

Comment: Как минимум должно быть `app = Frame(root)` и `lbl = Label(app, text = 'Вот она я!')`

Comment: Либо найдите данную книгу в более хорошем качестве, либо вообще не учите по ней.

Comment: Там не точка, а запятая. Вы читаете хреново отсканированную пиратскую копию.

Comment: Да, книга такая, нет другого. Ну, спасибо.

Comment: Я знаю как минимум 2 сайта на русском, по которым можно изучать tkinter: [Обучение Python GUI (уроки по Tkinter)](https://pythonru.com/uroki/obuchenie-python-gui-uroki-po-tkinter), [Курс по библиотеке Tkinter языка Python](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/Курс_по_библиотеке_Tkinter_языка_Python). Пытаться изучать что-то по скану книги в таком качестве - только трата времени.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, благодарю.

Answer (score -1):

может быть так заработает

```
from tkinter import * 

# Создание базового окна.
root = Tk()
root.title('Это я, метка')
root.geometry('200x50')

# Внутри окна создается рамка для размещения других элементов.
app =Frame(root)
app.grid()

# Создание метки внутри рамки.
lbl = Label(text = 'Вот она я!')
lbl.grid()

root.mainloop()
```